# ZigBee with RPi

Tags: xbee

I am thinking about making a ZigBee gateway/controller using RPi, and scouting for options. First of all, I would like to avoid an USB dongle, as I would like to encase everything.

So, a more "embedded" solution, eg. with XBee + GPIO could possibly work. However, there seems to be very few adapters for XBee out there. (I would also like to avoid soldering.. too lazy)

Anybody got a good take on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this ZigBee Raspberry Pi addon board by dresden elektronik wireless :

https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00E6300DO/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_dp_T1_uwrEzbRGYSHVD

Seems to have mixed reviews and i've not tried it myself.